# how do i ask a user to enter 2 numbers and then it will check which number is higher and print the higher number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def displaySmallest(num1, num2):
    print ("enter num 1")
    number1 = int(input())
    print("enter num 2")
    number2 = int(input())
    if (number1>number2):
        print("the first number is larger")
    elif (number2>number1):
        print("The second number is larger")
```

I'm not sure how to make functions work with user input

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your function isn't using and doesn't need its two arguments.

Comment: If you're asking "how do I call this function?", [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) may be useful to you.

Comment: minor nitpick but the name of the function could also be refined, as it doesn't actually displaySmallest, but the largest.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? What is it doing, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

Put the following code in `displaySmallest.py`:

```
def displaySmallest(num1, num2):
    print ("enter num 1")
    number1 = int(input())
    print("enter num 2")
    number2 = int(input())
    if (number1>number2):
        print("the first number is larger")
    elif (number2>number1):
        print("The second number is larger")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  displaySmallest()
```

Then type `python displaySmallest.py` at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
def displaySmallest():
print ("enter num 1")
number1 = int(input())
print("enter num 2")
number2 = int(input())
if (number1>number2):
    print("the first number is larger")
elif (number2>number1):
    print("The second number is larger")

displaySmallest()
```

You don't need to use these 2 arguments in this line:-

> def displaySmallest(**num1**, **num2**):

Because you are taking the input from within your function and *not passing value to it*. Although, if you want to keep the arguments, then you can try doing this :

```
def displaySmallest(num1, num2):
    number1 = num1
    number2 = num2
    if (number1>number2):
        print("the first number is larger")
    elif (number2>number1):
        print("The second number is larger")

print ("enter num 1")
number1 = int(input())

print("enter num 2")
number2 = int(input())

displaySmallest(number1, number2)
```

Hope this helps and have fun coding :) .

Answer (score 1):

The following program should do as you requested. Notice that it is possible that someone could enter the same number twice in a row. Code was added to take such an occurrence into account.

```
def main():
    first_number = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    second_number = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
    if first_number > second_number:
        print(first_number, 'is larger than', second_number)
    elif second_number > first_number:
        print(second_number, 'is larger than', first_number)
    else:
        print(first_number, 'is the same as', second_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```